# javascript - Jquery custom scroll bar on metro style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website with metro style them. I have multiply tile in it, and show horizontal scroll bar and it use with mouse wheel.

```
  #wrapper {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 90px 0px 1px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  } 
  #centerWrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto 15px;
  padding: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
  }
  #tileContainer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  }

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="centerWrapper">
      <div id="tileContainer" style="overflow: hidden">
         //Tiles
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  //show scroll bar
   <div class="scrollTools" style="position: absolute; display: block; opacity:     0;">
        <div class="draggerContainer">
            <div class="dragger" style="position: absolute; width: 1113px; left: 0px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                <div class="dragger_bar" style="position: relative;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="draggerRail"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But i don't want to use horizontal scroll bar, I want created a custom scroll bar like metro style, that use scroll when mouse enter in tiles, and hide when mouse leave.

I set `overflow: hidden;` for `tileContainer` to be displayed scroll bar of browser.

Does anyone have a nice plugin and a solution?

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnY8D/)**. mouse over on the text and you will see the result. if you want only vertical scroll you can use  overflow-x:hidden;

1. to change the default style of scroll you can use **::-webkit-scrollbar** styles
   you can write something like this:

   ```
   #tileContainer::-webkit-scrollbar
   {
     width: 9px;
     height: 9px;
    }

   #tileContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track
   {
     background: #ececec;
   } 

   #tileContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
   {
     background: #bebebe;
   }
   ```
2. if you want to display the scroll only on mouseenter you can use this code:

   ```
   $('#tileContainer').on('mouseenter',
    function(){
      $(this).css("overflow","auto");
    }).on('mouseleave',
   function(){
      $(this).css("overflow","hidden");
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, but it has 2 problem, 1. can change location of scroll bar(it is attached to the control). 2. can use mouse wheel for it?

Comment: 1. you can add ::-webkit-scrollbar to any control. if you see there is writen the div id -> #tileContainer. you can write there any control id and the scroll will appear on that control

Comment: 2. it works on mousewheel too. I don't understand the question

Comment: Thanks, i add this but don't work with mouse wheel,  should i add jquery for mouse wheel?

Comment: to make this js code work you have to include jquery of course. as you see in Demo that I referenced http://jsfiddle.net/LnY8D/ , mousewheel works.

Comment: Yes, it is work, but i have horizontal scroll bar, and don't work :(... Thanks a lot for solution.

Comment: sorry, i use this style but don't change scroll bar style!!!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4b3Wx/ here is the horizontal scroll example. I added additional js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4b3Wx/ is everything ok in this example. 
what browser do you use

Comment: Thanks, it is ok in chrome(style, mouse wheel) , but dont swt style in IE, and don't work style, mouse wheel in Mozila.

Comment: I use:   `$('#tileContainer').on('mousewheel', function (e,delta) {
                this.scrollLeft += (delta * 26);
                e.preventDefault();
            });`